# Usage of Variable Chart.Name in inherited Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've created a helm chart which contains some resources, which are reused in several other Helm charts:

```
base/templates/base.yaml

apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
```

Then I've created a helm chart which inherits the base chart and contains some special resources:

```
sub1/templates/sub1.yaml

...
name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
```

### Actual Output

In the actual output the resources of the base chart use always the chart name of the base chart.

```
---
# Source: sub1/templates/sub1.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sub1
---
# Source: sub1/charts/base/templates/base.yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: base
```

### Wanted output

But I want the chart name of the sub chart to be used in the base chart resources.

```
# Source: sub1/charts/base/templates/base.yaml
...
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: sub1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is a "Helm module"?  Is it a subchart, imported through `requirements.yaml` or `Chart.yaml`, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Module is the incorrect term. I mean chart.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to reuse the resources via [named templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/):

```
base/templates/base.yaml

{{- define "base-lib.secret-provider-class" -}}
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
{{- end -}}


sub1/templates/sub1.yaml

{{ include "base-lib.secret-provider-class" . }}
---
...
```